# How to joint together many boxes on model editor

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using Gazebo 9.9.0.

I have modeled this on model editor:

[image: image description]

Is there any way to joint together those  12 boxes to have only one box?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/23106/how-to-joint-together-many-boxes-on-model-editor/) by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can make a model containing all of the boxes.

Inside Gazebo, you would place one box, then right click on it and choose 'Edit model'. Then shape and position the box and add the rest of the boxes. Once you are satisfied with the model, press Ctrl+S or choose 'save' from the upper menu. Your model will be saved into your models folder and you will be able to insert it into your worlds any time from the 'Insert' tab.

[image description http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14915540539448007.png](http://answers.gazebosim.org/upfiles/14915540539448007.png)

If your boxes fly away from each other, you can either put 'fixed' joint between the boxes inside the model editor, or set them static.

[image: image description]
If you set the boxes to 'static' they won't move even if they are not all part of the same model.

---

Originally posted by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) with karma: 755 on 2019-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VansFannel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4697/vansfannel/) on 2019-07-03**:
Thanks a lot. I can't up vote more.